# Oracle 10g SQL regexp like

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, oracle, oracle10g

I'd like to ask if it's possible in a regexp to identify in a given number if there are 3 instances of a set.

For instance:

```
123456141414
123456171717
```

in the example above we have 3x14 and 3x17 so it should return the numbers in the regexp_like query.

But it should return all occurrences of 3 times the same numbers.

Comment: Any code that shows your current attempts?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
SELECT INPUT_TEXT, REGEXP_SUBSTR(INPUT_TEXT, '([[:digit:]]{2})\1\1', 6) EXTRACTED
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE REGEXP_INSTR(INPUT_TEXT, '([[:digit:]]{2})\1\1', 6) > 0
```

Input table values:

```
 INPUT_TEXT
--------------
 123456141414
 123456171717
 123456111111
 141414123456
 123456121234
```

Query result:

```
 INPUT_TEXT        EXTRACTED
--------------   --------------
 123456111111       111111
 123456141414       141414
 123456171717       171717
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks Reza but the pattern is only 12 digits and your suggestion returns as well a match pattern with 111 for instance. In a given pattern of 12 digits it should find the last 8 digits being pairs like (XXXXXX111111, XXXXXX121212, and so on.) Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: If you need to catch only double-digit triples, then use this expression: `([[:digit:]]{2})\1\1`

Comment: Almost good but still returns pattern which matches only 2 times double-digit instead of 3 times.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the match should only be valid for the last 6 digits it should not include the first 6 digits.

Comment: @user1814129 Updated the post. Hope this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your updated requirements correctly, you're checking that you have six digits followed by a pair of digits repeated three times.  In which case, Reza's response should be modified to:

```
select * from (
select '123456343434' str from dual union all
select '123456555555' str from dual union all
select '1234565555550' str from dual union all
select '123456232324' str from dual union all
select '123456111110' str from dual )
where regexp_like(str,'^([[:digit:]]{6})([[:digit:]]{2})\2\2$')
```

which gives:

```
STR          
123456343434 
123456555555
```

Editted to add - if you want to extract the actual digit-pair that's repeated:

```
select regexp_replace(str,'^([[:digit:]]{6})([[:digit:]]{2})\2\2$','\2') result 
from (
select '123456343434' str from dual union all
select '123456555555' str from dual union all
select '123456555555a' str from dual union all
select '123456232324' str from dual union all
select '123456111110' str from dual )
where regexp_like(str,'^([[:digit:]]{6})([[:digit:]]{2})\2\2$')
```